# Segmentation fault in publishing array message

Tags: geometry-msgs, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to publish polygonal position as message. The publisher is make correct but "segmentation error" shows when I rosrun the publisher, saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "line_formation");
    ros::NodeHandle na;
    geometry_msgs::Polygon destination;

    ros::Subscriber sub= na.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("/joy",1,joyCallback);
    ros::Publisher pub= na.advertise<geometry_msgs::Polygon>("uav_positions",10);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(2);

   while (ros::ok)
   {
      central_x +=array[4]; 
      central_y +=-array[3];
      central_z +=array[1];

      destination.points[0].x=central_x;
      destination.points[0].y=central_y;
      destination.points[0].z=central_z;

      pub.publish(destination);
      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
   }
}
```

As it shows, I use message "geometry_msgs/Polygon". It seems its caused by publishing array. If I publish single point message as "geometry_msgs/Point", it works. But I need to publish several points. So I have to publish array.

Any idea how to solve it or other ways to publish several points position?

Thanks
Glen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188614/segmentation-fault-in-publishing-array-message/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++ ROS messages, variable-sized arrays are implemented as a `std::vector`, which start with a size of 0. You're probably getting a segmentation fault because you're trying to use an array index that is out of bounds.

You should probably call `resize()` to set the size of the points array:

```
destination.points.resize(1);
```

If you're interested in learning more about the std::vector, my favorite reference is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2014-08-01**:
It shows "geometry_msgs::Polygon has no member named 'resize' ". I'm nor sure is that because declaration of "geometry_msgs/Polygon". Still reading the reference you sent to me, trying to figure it out.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2014-08-01**:
Sorry, it worked! I make a typing error when resize it. Thanks!